# Join row with specified field value and highest value in other field

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables:
**Articles:**
ID INTEGER
...
**Article_versions:**
article INTEGER
lang ENUM
time TIMESTAMP
PRIMARY KEY( article,lang,time ) 
...
I want to select fields from Articles and fields from related latest row Article_versions.
Should i use join or 2 select statements?
And how can i do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is confusing exactly what information you are trying to retrieve but if you know a particular ID then you can use:

```
SELECT ID,lang,time
FROM articles,article_versions
WHERE articles.ID=<article_id_you_provide> AND
      articles.ID=article_versions.article AND
      article_versions.time = (SELECT max(time)
                               FROM article_versions
                               WHERE article=<article_id_you_provide>);
```

Let me know if this isn't what you are looking for and I can revise my answer further.

Comment: yes, it's doing what i want. But what about the performance, isn't this slower than join or it's same as join?

Comment: well doing it this way is a join in a sense because it takes takes the cross product of the two tables and the where clauses filter. The reason why I didn't use join syntax is because your foreign key in article_versions isn't the same name as articles so it would be messy to do a natural join too.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming [Articles_versions].[time] would be the only unique column returned in the join set you could use the following:

```
SELECT [Articles].[ID], [Articles_versions].[article], [Articles_versions].[lang], MAX([Articles_versions].[time])
FROM Articles Inner Join Articles_versions ON [Articles].[ID] = [Articles_versions].[article]
GROUP BY [Articles].[ID], [Articles_versions].[article], [Articles_versions].[lang]
```

Comment: this doesn't fetch latest article versions. So MAX(time) is the newest, but other fields from article_versions aren't